# Making a star triangle using javascript function recursively

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am pretty new to programming, I am getting to know JavaScript, and I've just learned the notion of recursion. Now I am given a problem, to create a function (like `const f = function(n) { }`) and if we if we call the function with `f(5)`, we should see:

```
     *
    ***
   *****
  *******
 *********
```

The number of vertical stars must be determined by the input.
I've got to use no for/while/do-while; recursion only to loop.

I've come up with this code to concatenate 5 stars

```
const f = function(n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return "";
  }
  return  "*" +  f(n - 1);
};

 console.log(f(5));
```

Though, I don't see how to make the triangle, what can I do?

Comment: Use a while or for function

Comment: not allowed to use for the homework

Comment: @O.Rares the task OP has specifically asks to not use loops

Comment: @O.Rares It says recursively in the title

Comment: Exactly nothing but recursion

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan What output do you get now?

Comment: @AndrewL. With the code above?

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan Yeah

Comment: @AndrewL. I get *****

Comment: @AndrewL.  but I need the triangle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this code:

```js
const f = function(chr, n) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return "";
  }
  return  chr +  f(chr, n - 1);
};
const g = function(max) {
   const inner = function(n) {
       if (n > 1) {
           inner(n-1);
       }
       console.log(f(' ', max-n) + f('*', (n*2)-1));
   };
   inner(max);
};
g(5);
```

Comment: This works perfectly , but I the essence of the problem is avoid using for
I can't even use var, const only, and recursion

Comment: @ErikHambardzumyan I've updated the code with recursive version.

Comment: it has to be like g(5) not g(5,5)

Answer (score 1):

Please see and play the example below

```js
function pyramid(n, row = 0, level = '') {

if (row === n) {
    return
}

if (level.length === n * 2 - 1) {
    console.log(level)
    return pyramid(n, row + 1)
}

const midpoint = Math.floor((2 * n - 1) / 2)

let add;
if (midpoint - row <= level.length && midpoint + row >= level.length) {
    add = '#'
} else {
    add = ' '
}

pyramid(n, row, level + add)
}

pyramid(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right way with the

```
 if (n === 0) ...
```

and the

```
f(n-1)
```

these are correct already.

Now you just need to output the correct number of stars in every function call. Look at [string.repeat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/repeat) for that.

If you want to see a complete solution and not just a hint: [here](http://pastebin.com/gRN4pfzw) is my solution.

Comment: it's got to be something were we must use recursion only, nothing but recursion and no var or let, only const. That's the problem

Comment: That sounds like stupid requirements. But here you go: http://pastebin.com/NTX2CWAE

Comment: you should put your code in the actual answer - it's a good one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function recursiveStar(n){
if(n === 0) return 0;
recursiveStar(n - 1);
return console.log('*'.repeat(n));
}
recursiveStar(5)
```

Comment: Hey there.  Welcome to SO.  Code-only answers without explanatory content are generally frowned upon.  Consider adding some text outside your code block explaining what you're doing, how it addresses the question, or something else to help introduce the reader to your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
function pyramid(n, row = 0) {
  if (n === row) return;
  let midpoint = Math.ceil((n + n - 1) / 2);
  let str = "";
  for (let j = 1; j <= n + n - 1; j++) {
    if (j <= midpoint + row && j >= midpoint - row) str += "#";
    else str += " ";
  }
  console.log(str);
  pyramid(n, row + 1);
}

pyramid(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

As this old question has recently been brought back up, here's an alternative version that treats the depth as constant and recurs on the row number:

```js
const pyramid = (n, r = 0) => 
  r > n - 1 
    ? '' 
    : ' '.repeat ((n - 1 - r)) + '*'.repeat ((2 * r + 1)) + '\n' + pyramid (n, r + 1) 

console .log (pyramid (5))
```

We keep `n` fixed, starting `r` at zero, and then recursively incrementing `r` until it's greater than `n`.  In our base case, when `n` is `0` and `r` is `0`, we get `r > n - 1`, and return an empty string.  The recursive case proceeds by adding the right number of spaces, the the right number of starts to our first row, and calculating the remaining rows by incrementing `r`, and recurring.

```js
const pyramid = (n, r = 0) => 
  r > n - 1 
    ? '' 
    : ' ' .repeat ((n - 1 - r)) + '*' .repeat ( (2 * r + 1)) + '\n' + pyramid (n, r + 1) 
//    `-----------------------'   `------------------------'   `--'   `----------------'
//                |                           |                  |             |
//                |                           |                  |             +-- next rows
//                |                           |                  +---------------- line break
//                |                           +----------------------------------- asterisks
//                +--------------------------------------------------------------- empty spaces
```

The only slight trickiness in that is the calculation of the correct number of stars and spaces.  It's pretty easy to see that for `pyramid (5)`, the spaces should decrease steadily from `4` down to `0` and the asterisks should increase from `1` up to `9`.  These are captured by the formulas `n - 1 - r` and `2 * r + 1` respectively.

This was originally for an assignment, and if that assignment didn't allow us to use `String.prototype.repeat`, then we could easily write our own recursive version in a function like this:

```js
const repeat = (c, n) => 
  n < 1 ? '' : c + repeat (c, n - 1)

const pyramid = (n, r = 0) => 
  r > n - 1 
    ? '' 
    : repeat (' ', (n - 1 - r)) + repeat ('*', (2 * r + 1)) + '\n' + pyramid (n, r + 1)
```